# Match "81" in "630.81.11" using regex

Tags: regex

I want to match "81" in "630.81.11". I'm stuck with `\.[0-9]*\.` which includes the dots.

Comment: Which language are you using? What function call are you using?

Comment: Its for use in a PostGreSQL query. I need to sort by the three parts. Something like:

ORDER BY substring(plannr from '^[0-9]*')::integer,substring(plannr from '\.[0-9][0-9]\.')::interger,substring(plannr from '[0-9]*$')::integer

The middle part is the problem - cant cast it to integer with the dots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** After seeing what problem you are trying to solve, I would suggest not using regular expressions.

> Its for use in a PostGreSQL query. I need to sort by the three parts. Something like:

```
ORDER BY
    substring(plannr from '^[0-9]*')::integer,
    substring(plannr from '\.[0-9][0-9]\.')::interger,
    substring(plannr from '[0-9]*$')::integer
```

Instead of using a regular expression you can use for example `split_part`:

```
SELECT plannr
FROM table1
ORDER BY
    split_part(plannr, '.', 1)::integer,
    split_part(plannr, '.', 2)::integer,
    split_part(plannr, '.', 3)::integer;
```

Result:

```
"2.2.3"
"2.10.3"
"2.10.20"
"10.1.4"
"630.81.11"
```

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (plannr VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO table1 (plannr) VALUES
('630.81.11'),
('2.2.3'),
('2.10.3'),
('2.10.20'),
('10.1.4');
```

---

**Original answer:** If your regular expression engine includes fixed length lookaheads and lookbehinds you can do this:

```
(?<=\.)[0-9]+(?=\.)
```

Answer (score 10):

```
/^[0-9]+\.([0-9]+)\.[0-9]+$/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can enclose the interesting part in a group, and later extract it. So, something like "\.([0-9]*)\."; the parens denote a group.

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\.(\\d+)\\.");
String str = "630.81.11";
Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(str);

while (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

I've tested it in Java. The output is as follows:

> 81